# C# .NET Core ImageConverter

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, system.drawing

I am trying to use the `ImageConverter` class in my ASP.NET Core project to convert an `Image` to a `byte[]`, but I can't seem to find the class.

I have installed the *System.Drawing.Common* package, but still can't find it.

I am using .NET Core 3.1.

Comment: What exactly to do expect to find inside that byte array? The raw contents of the image's pixel data? Or a saved file in a known format?

Answer (score 3):

If on .NET Core 3.1, `ImageConverter` requires the `System.Windows.Extensions` package:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imageconverter?view=netcore-3.1

In .NET 5 it is included in `System.Drawing.Common`:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imageconverter?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ImageConverter, you can trying to look at this for speed up:

Save bitmap to stream:

```
bitmap.save(stream);
```

Or open image file:

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream(imageFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

Then simply use Stream2Bytes:

```
byte[] OO7b = Stream2Bytes(stream);
```

And this is the Stream2Bytes method:

```
public byte[] Stream2Bytes(Stream stream, int chunkSize = 1024)
{
    if (stream == null)
    {
        throw new System.ArgumentException("Parameter cannot be null", "stream");
    }

    if (chunkSize < 1)
    {
        throw new System.ArgumentException("Parameter must be greater than zero", "chunkSize");
    }

    if (chunkSize > 1024 * 64)
    {
        throw new System.ArgumentException(String.Format("Parameter must be less or equal {0}", 1024 * 64), "chunkSize");
    }

    List<byte> buffers = new List<byte>();

    using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(stream))
    {
        byte[] chunk = br.ReadBytes(chunkSize);

        while (chunk.Length > 0)
        {
            buffers.AddRange(chunk);
            chunk = br.ReadBytes(chunkSize);
        }
     }

     return buffers.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: That just saves it to png format. Also, you can just as well just save it to a `MemoryStream` right away and call `.ToArray()` on that.

Comment: Absolutely, that means without buffering. But that will need more resource usage which could influence to scalability and performance, especially for large file.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert image to byte easily.

```
protected virtual byte[] LoadPictureFromFile(string filePath)
{
   if (!File.Exists(filePath))
       return new byte[0];

   return File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
}
```

Extra help..

```
    public byte[] ResizeImage(byte[] pictureBinary,int newWidth, int newHeight)
    {
        byte[] pictureBinaryResized;
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(pictureBinary))
        {
            Bitmap b = null;
            try
            {
                //try-catch to ensure that picture binary is really OK. Otherwise, we can get "Parameter is not valid" exception if binary is corrupted for some reasons
                b = new Bitmap(stream);
            }
            catch (ArgumentException exc)
            {
              // log error
            }

            if (b == null)
            {
                //bitmap could not be loaded for some reasons
                return new byte[0];
            }

            using (var destStream = new MemoryStream())
            {

                ImageBuilder.Current.Build(b, destStream, new ResizeSettings
                {
                    Width = newWidth,
                    Height = newHeight,
                    Scale = ScaleMode.Both,
                    Quality = _mediaSettings.DefaultImageQuality
                });
                pictureBinaryResized = destStream.ToArray();
                b.Dispose();
            }
        }

        return pictureBinaryResized;
    }
```